Modification to be able to print results of each frame alone
I'm working on a task with the HM encoder and want to output the results for each frame after encoding, such as PSNR, type, and MSE. Is there a something directly allows this, or the source code need modification? If anyone has already did that, I would greatly appreciate your help.
I found in the source code  in the TEncGOP.cpp the function that is responsible to output the result under different conditions , but I am somehow stuck and I cant proceed with the modification
